# Saving and restoring the brightness setting of a display

Tags: display, system-settings

I have a dual monitor display and I calibrate both displays. My calibrator generates a calibration profile for each monitor, however the brightness is not saved to the profile (apparently this is the same with all calibrators). This means that although I can now switch between profiles with ease, if I change the brightness of a monitor (deliberately or accidentally), I have no way of getting back to the brightness that is correct for the profile.

Is there any way I can save and restore the brightness of each monitor?

Note: When I say *brightness* I am talking about the Brightness slider found in System Prefs > Displays. The slider offers no clue as to the numeric value of the brightness, so there is no way to return to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use the open source command line tool, [brightness](https://github.com/nriley/brightness), to set the value on-demand. This way you could find your preferred brightness value and apply that value as needed, or per-profile.

Mac OS X Hints' discussion on [Adjust brightness from Terminal](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090901021817717) covers the tool, how to compile it, and possible scripts to extend its use.

OS X Daily has also covered the tool in [Adjust screen brightness from command line](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/28/adjust-screen-brightness-from-command-line/).

Comment: I've added a separate answer with detailed steps. Feel free to copy-paste over to your answer and delete my answer.

Comment: Does the `brightness` tool do what you need? If so, good to hear you found a workable solution.

Comment: New home for brightness on [GitHub](https://github.com/nriley/brightness).

Comment: @FranklinYu thank you. I have updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This just adds a basic how-to to Graham Miln's answer.

1. Download source from [here](http://dev.sabi.net/svn/dev/trunk/LocationDo/brightness.c).
2. Open Commandline
3. Run `gcc -std=c99 -o brightness brightness.c -framework IOKit -framework ApplicationServices` This will create a binary in the same location

To print display(s) brightness:

1. Run `/path/to/binary/brightness -l`

This will print for example:

display 0: main display, ID 0x42b19a8
display 0: brightness 0.282261
display 1: ID 0x4248e66
display 1: brightness 0.781247

To set display brightness

1. Run `/path/to/binary/brightness -d {display index} {display value}`

Replace {display index} with the numerical index of the display as shown when printing the brightness value. Replace {display value} with a number between 0 and 1.